# iCloud, Core Data, migration and model mapping

Tags: ios, core-data, core-data-migration, icloud

As said in the [Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/DataManagement/RN-iCloudCoreData/_index.html)

> Schema migration using mapping models is not supported (lightweight
>   migration is supported).

I was wondering about options we have in case we need to deal with iCloud fonctionnality and mapping model migration... I know that I will need to change my Core Data model in the future to add functionalities to my application (and not only in a lightweight way). The thing is that I can't say now which new entities will be needed and which relationships with previous model entities will be set.

I was thinking about a sequence like that:

> 1 - Launching my app doing the mapping migration of my Core Data Model
>
> 2 - Letting it synchronized with iCloud

This will work if iCloud contains transaction log files adapted to the new Model. In case of old transaction log files (means adapted to the old Model) it will failed.

To avoid that I was thinking about doing:

> 1 - Launching my app letting it synchronized with iCloud
>
> 2 - Doing the mapping migration of my Core Data Model
>
> 3 - Removing old iCloud data updating it with the new one

This will not work if iCloud already contains updated transaction log files (means adapted to the new Model).

What I need is a way to check if transaction logs in iCloud are compatible with my current Core Data Model. Is there a way to do this ?

Thanks.

Comment: What seems possible to do is to use the iCloud key-value to store a model version that you can check either before creating your persistent store coordinator or doing a model mapping. I would like to had that for now the iPhoneRecipes example available on apple iCloud forum which show the use of iCloud and Core Data is still not stable. Syncing does not always succeed and sometimes connection to iCloud fails. I think I will not use iCloud in combination with Core Data before an update from Apple.

Answer (score 2):

I would not recommend using Core Data with iCloud in a production app.

Its not stable enough. There is no simple way of checking if the app is en/disabled in the iCloud settings. And not to mention the problems that can arise if the user turns the iCloud support off after having it enabled.

Migrations are another issue. Lightweight migration works fairly well. But in order to make a mapping model migration work, you need to clean out/evict content from the existing iCloud "ubiquity folder", create a new one (with a new name) and change the value associated with NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentURLKey. And, you need to make sure that all clients do the same. Its complex but doable. Not sure if its worth it though...

Regarding the version compatibility issue, I've not yet tried it, but an idea would be to somehow get the store metadata from an iCloud transaction log and through the "compatibleWithStoreMetadata" method on ManagedObjectModel check if the version matches:

```
// Get current model
NSManagedObjectModel *myModel = [self managedObjectModel];

// Check compatibility
BOOL isCompatible = [myModel isConfiguration:nil compatibleWithStoreMetadata: metadataFromTransactionLogEntry];
```